# How to lock a set of EJBs to avoid executions until one "master" EJB has been processed?

Tags: jakarta-ee, locking, ejb-3.1

I have a composition of multiple EJBs in a MasterEJB.
The MasterEJB itself is executing all referenced EJBs. See the example:

```
@Singleton
public class MasterEJB {
   @EJB
   A myA;
   @EJB
   B myB;
   @EJB
   C myC;

   @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
   public void execute() {
      myA.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();
      myB.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();
      myC.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();
   }
}
```

The issue is, that the methods `myA.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();`, `myB.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();` and `myC.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();` must not be executed outside from any different caller until MasterEJB#execute() is executed properly.

But how to achieve this?

I am on a JEE7 container (Wildfly 8/Wildfly 10)

Comment: will execute() run more than once?

Comment: Jaumzera, no execute() can only run once (no parallel execution)

Comment: What kind of SessionBeans A, B and C are? And how about their methods "doSmethingWhichTakesAges"? Can they run afterwards?

Comment: do not get the point exactly. What do you have in mind? Maybe I can answer better afterwards?

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to move the logic behind "doSomethingWhichTakesAges"s to another kind of class. They really need to be SessionBeans? Because if they were Stateless or Stateful session beans, IMHO, thats impossible and one of main reasons is the SLSB pooling.

Comment: the referenced EJBs A, B, C are all independently callable and in our case they are singletons. The issue is, if the MasterEJB is getting processed we do not want to have the other EJBs (A,B,C) getting called to avoid issues in the processing.

Comment: You can use `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)` on client beans A, B, C and manage the acces by using some kind of logic in the relevant method.

Comment: Leonardo, do you have a example? I do not get the solution with the @ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN) you have mentioned.

Comment: With `@ConcurrencyManagement(BEAN)` you won't restrict access to the other EBJs, as you're asking for, but just to the annotated one. Nothing will prevent other enterprise beans to call A, B or C.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been following your post for some time and, once you didn't get a concrete response, I'd like to suggest you to try something like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MasterEJB {
   @EJB
   private A myA;
   private boolean aRead;

   @EJB
   private B myB;
   private boolean aRead;

   @EJB
   private C myC;
   private boolean aRead;

   public void execute() {
      myA.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();
      myB.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();
      myC.doSomethingWhichTakesAges();
   }

   // GSO (getters and setters omitted)
}

@Stateless
public class A {

    @EJB
    private MasterEJB masterEJB;

    public void doSomethingWhichTakesAges() {
        // your logic...
        masterEJB.setARead(true);
    }

    public void anyOtherMethod() {
        if(masterEJB.isARead()) {
            // execute your logic
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException("...");
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I'm still thinking in a way to solve your problem. Yesterday I've realized that you can define an interceptor to do the job for you.

```java
@Interceptor
public class StateCheckInterceptor {

    @EJB
    private MasterEJB masterEJB;     

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object checkIfReady(InvokedContext context) throws Exception {
        // check if your masterEJB has done its job
        return context.proceed(); 
    }
```

So you can annotate your beans (or use XML-based approach) to use it before executing every (or each) method.

Here's the spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkigq.html
Take a look. 
I hope it helps.